The Additive Identity Besides Closing Under Addition?
This is an exercise from Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right:
The set of differentiable real-valued functions f on the interval $(0, 3)$ such that $f'(2)=b$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{(0,3)}$ if and only if $b=0$.
I know that this question has been asked before in this link:Subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{(0,3)}$, and I know this doesn't satisfy a subspace since it's not closed under addition.
However, I'm slightly confused on if the additive identity exists in this subspace. Is $f(x)=0$ for $x$ in $(0,3)$ the additive identity in the function set? If so, then $f'(2)$ must be $0$. Does this count as a proof?

Yes, $f(x)=0$ is the only choice for the additive identity. For any $g(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{(0,3)}, g(x)+f(x)=f(x)+g(x)=g(x).$

Alright, thanks!
